# create a button that can only be pressed once

Tags: python, function, button

i am trying to create a button that can only be pressed once for a game in python but i cant figure out how to set a variable that works in the def and does not change every time the function is run.

```
tut = turtle.Screen()._root
def bt1():
    pressed = 1
    x_turn = True
    if (pressed == 1):
        if (x_turn is True):
            print("this button has not been pressed as player1")
            x_turn == False
            pressed = 0
        else:
            print ("this button has not been pressed as player2")
            pressed = 0
            x_turn == True
    else:
        print("this button has been pressed")

photo1 = Image.open(r"C:\image.png")
resize_photo1 =photo1.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
print_photo1 = itk.PhotoImage(resize_photo1)
Button(tut, image= print_photo1,command=bt1).pack(side= LEFT)
```

Comment: What are you using for build the button? Otherwise, this is just a function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. It's not clear: 1) Just what is "a button" in your program? If you are using, for example, `tkinter` or another GUI library, please explicitly say so and use the appropriate tag for the question; and make sure that there is enough code that we can copy and paste it to see the problem directly. 2) **What happens** when you try this code? **How is that different** from what you expect to happen? In other words, what is actually your **question about** this code?

Comment: Also, please try to [study the code carefully yourself first](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). What do you see happening, step by step, when the code runs? Does `x_turn` get changed in the way that you expect it to? (Hint: what do you expect the code `x_turn == False` to do? Why?) Also, what does "pressed as x" and "pressed as y" mean, and how is that related to the question? I thought you wanted a button that can only be pressed once, but it looks like you are trying to create one that can only be pressed *twice*.

Comment: thank you for you feedback i think i have clear it up more

Answer (score 0):

what i am gathering is that when this button is pressed you want it to set pressed to 0 so it can not run again but since you put the variable at the top every time the button is bressed it will set it to 1. to fix this all you want to do is....

```
tut = turtle.Screen()._root
global pressed
pressed = 1
global x_turn
x_turn = True
def bt1():
    if (pressed == 1):
        if (x_turn is True):
            print("this button has not been pressed as player1")
            x_turn == False
            pressed = 0
```

This might work let me know if it does

Comment: sorry but no it still loops and still don't have a solution

Answer (score -1):

x_turn = True

Try using this :

x_turn == True

I think here you’re missing the equals to sign and that’s why it is creating a problem.

Comment: while what might work for you when i try it it comes with this error:                     x_turn == True
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x_turn' referenced before assignment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).